# Jquery animate error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, jquery-animate

it's 3 am right now and I'm not the best at jquery, can someone tell me what stupid mistake I'm making?

I have it in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/7GWRp/

There's a kink in css transitions that don't allow them to be used on :before or :after elements, so I'm trying to do a workaround using jquery which is already being used on the page. Basically these are the three css state normal, hover, and active.

(I'm trying to animate the little shine at the top)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.button:before').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '0px',
            opacity: 1
          }, 100);
    });
    $('.button:before').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '30px',
            opacity: 0
          }, 100);
    });
    $('.button:before').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left : '-30px',
            opacity : '1'
          }, 100);
    });

});
```

Comment: not the shine at the top

Comment: @cambraca I updated the post with more info

Comment: @Chetan I updated the post with more info

Comment: And it looks pretty damn cool too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verdict [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery) is that, since pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, they cannot be directly targeted with jQuery.

Inserting a physical element like `<div class="button gray"><span></span>Button</div>` seems to me to be the easiest solution but it does clutter the markup...

Comment: Instead of adding a `span` in the HTML, add one using jQuery.